# Rule 1: Be nice!

Tags: discussion

So there's a couple of meta questions about this, and it's been discussed at length in the chat room, and the mods' chat room.

What it comes down to:

- Stackexchange has rules about being nice.  We've been very lenient with these rules. We will no longer be.
- **Insults / personal attacks will result in suspensions.  Further infringements could result in bans.  We will be being tough on this - don't risk it!**
- Politics is part of travel.  Everyone has a different view.  Be tolerant of other views.
- insults don't have to be against a person - if you are targeting a race, ethnic group, place or otherwise
- If you can buy a flight there, the place exists, for the purposes of Stackexchange.  If people want to travel there, telling them it doesn't exist helps nobody.
- Do NOT argue politics or off-topic stuff in comments. If it goes back and forth more than twice, it's best to take it to the chat room.
- Join the chat room! We have heated debates, fun chats, random discussions. And nothing's off topic there - although the be nice rule still applies.

Thanks all, now let's talk travel!

Comment: +1 just for the title alone!

Comment: I wouldn't bother to use the word "country" here though Mark. I would just put "place".

Comment: +1 for the new title too dammit!

Comment: I would even go as far as to say "If you can travel there, the place exists for he purpose of travel.se" - just in case there are no publicly available plane tickets.

Comment: Not exactly a question... :P

Answer (score 14):

I truly support this thread. I come from [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), which is known to be one of the friendliest sites on SE. Trust me that it is good and important to be friendly!

I would add a Rule 1a:

- Vote up if the question is well stated.
- If you think the question can be improved, say it nicely in the comments.
- Think **twice** (or **3 times** maybe) before you down-vote, **especially** if it is a **newcomer** asking. It is much better to teach people how to ask than to discourage them from going here by a negative attitude towards them!

Comment: Glad to see that some people think that civility and general friendliness have not been lost to the otherwise dry personality of the Internet !