# Clarification about delete vote

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Someone voted to delete [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49814/753).

I'm the only one who called the troll's bluff, and now it's clear to everyone that he was just trolling you.

The amount of downvotes there is a testament to his success.

So, not only you abundantly feed the troll, now you also want to censor people who spot him and give a proper answer? Seriously? 33 years of Internet and we are still at that point?

Comment: It's sad that after 33 years, people still cannot express their opinion on the web without insulting others.

Comment: I am happy this troll is gone forever :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow. An easily fixed rant, as @RoflcoptrException has easily done - remove the insult.

Then we address the question.  Lohoris, I just looked through your history, there's a lot of calling people trolls and even your profile description could be perceived as passive aggressive.  I realise you're trying to raise a problem that you've spotted, but good news - the website already has systems in place for this.

- voting - you upvote good, useful answers. downvote bad or wrong ones.
- flagging - if one is offensive or otherwise an issue, you flag it for a mod.

Together, as a community the votes are collected, and the 'wisdom' (in quotes because sometimes the hive mind goes a little off track) of the community sorts things out. Usually. Not always, which is when mods or meta comes in.

What we don't have as a system behaviour:
 - rhetorical insults
 - name calling
 - general rudeness

[Rule 1: Be nice!](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/rule-1-be-nice)

If you get insulted, don't respond. Just flag it. Don't worry, the mods don't accept rudeness.  Like you yourself said, don't feed the 'trolls'.

In this question the community has actually given you some upvotes, and sure, someone(?) tried to delete it. It went through the system and as far as I can see, the vote suggestion failed. Success, the system works!

Also worth hopping into [chat] occasionally, you can help direct the hive mind a bit by discussing it openly - it's also much more of a free-form discussion in there, save for direct insults, you can pretty much speak your mind :D

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 14):

> now you also want to censor people who spot him and give a proper answer

The main problem with your answer is, that you don't address the OP's question at all. The question is "Can aircrew order me not to stand in the aisle?" and the other 3 answers clearly address the fact that the aircrew indeed has the power to do this, while your answer doesn't even mention anything about that. That was the reason why I downvoted the question. (I did not however vote to delete it)

If you think that the question asked is inappropriate for this site, writing and answer is not the right tool to do so. You can flag the question for the attention of a moderator. You can also downvote the question if you think it's not useful. Furthermore, once you'll have enough reputation for that, you will be able to cast close votes on questions. However, answering is purely for answering the question, and not to question the OP's intentions or motives.

In my opinion, I think this is a good and useful question, which potentially is important to a lot of people. Of course I don't know whether the user is actually Muslim, or whether he actually faces this problem, but I really don't see how any of that would decrease the value of this question. I also fail to see how this question is confrontational, it is formulated in a very neutral tone, without any rant or side blows which often characterise confrontational questions on this site.

Lastly, please do read the part about [being nice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) in the help centre.

Comment: Just a note, indeed an answer cannot be closed but deleted. Closing just makes the question marked as closed and unanswerable, deleting makes a post invisible to most users.

Comment: @Vince oh, I wondered about that. Oh, I see it now, that's a privilege one only gets above 20k, no wonder I never saw the option. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: He becomes confrontational and aggressive in the comments. Which are mostly deleted now, of course.

Comment: @Lohoris aggressive? you mean after you tried to insult Arabs and Muslims?

Comment: @Lohoris I don't see how that is relevant to the question you posted here, as here the issue you raise is with the reaction to your answer and not with the comments.

Comment: He answered the underlying question of "How do I handle my prayer mid flight?" with "Delay your prayer until landed or schedule the flight for when you don't need to pray" going through the XY-problem of praying during flight.

Comment: `Of course I don't know whether the user is actually Muslim` - we don't have to. Take the text at face value, praise the "death of the author" concept and move on to add useful information to the web. ditto.

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't matter **who** asks a question or **why** (though why can sometimes be useful or interesting), only **what** they ask. Take each question at face value. If User's... *curious* questions were each asked by different people, no-one would be freaking out. Each one, individually, is on-topic and interesting. Collectively, they're a bit odd... (maybe he's a small-time courier with... *interesting* clients) but even if he was trying to troll us by provoking interesting, on-topic content that raises the profile of the site, who cares?

Answer (score 9):

I am one of the <strike>stupid</strike> people who voted to delete the answer, as I usually do when I see someone trying to fill the space with nonsense instead of a real answer. It's a privilege I have and I use as I see fit.

If one day I made the wrong decision, that will not harm anyone as my single vote is not enough to delete the answer. It needs three votes for the answer to be deleted, and it is kinda rare for three users with enough rep to take a wrong decision and if that happens, Meta is there to discuss the issue and then another three users can simply undelete, or one single vote from a mod is enough.

So take it easy and stop calling people names, this won't help you.

Comment: Neither supporting a troll will help the site.

Comment: @Lohoris I don't believe he is.

Comment: [Seriously?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49738/can-aircrew-order-me-not-to-stand-in-the-aisle) If you think this post, and especially his attitude in this post, is normal, I'm **REALLY** worried.

Comment: @Lohoris Yes, I am a cabin crew member and I get that question a lot in person from passengers. Even if he wasn't a Muslim, it is perfectly fine to have an inquisitive mind and ask questions.

Comment: @NeAnDerthal [Either I have a time machine or I have planned for pretending to be Muslim since January.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52773/what-is-a-friendly-alternative-to-the-word-brother-that-can-be-used-by-a-musli)

Comment: @User how did you get to that question? just curious...

Comment: @Mindwin sorry I am not following?! I am the OP in that question

Comment: @User I did not access your network profile, you are under different user names in the two network sites. My bad. Move on. XD

Comment: But NeanDerThal is correct, the fact that the OP (@User) is a muslim or not (even if he claims to be so) is irrelevant. What really matters is if the question is a good question or not. We have to stop looking for "hidden intent" after a short while, or paranoia will take over. Is the Question good? Will it be useful to someone reaching for the site? good. Vote, answer, read and move on.

Comment: @User: `Either I have a time machine or I have planned for pretending to be Muslim since January.` - you hacked the SE servers and the google cache. Just kidding.

Answer (score -6):

I am glad that you came with this question especially that you are calling the rest of the community stupid.

---

Anyway, since you guys decided to turn SE into Reddit IAmA, here is the proof:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
Guys anybody wants to meet in person in London I don't mind

You will be able to see where I work and that would clarify what have been accusing me with ie trolling & lying

I would love to meet [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**Edit2**

Must be a very dedicated troll! Two jobs, two children yet have the time to do exams and visit SE daily!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether this was partially triggered by me writing 'Of course I don't know whether the user is actually Muslim' in my answer. I was trying to outline the fact that it is irrelevant to the quality of the question whether you are or not. It was not my intention to imply that I don't believe you. I think the success of your question (and the number of negative votes on the answer in question) talks for itself and you should not let yourself feel cornered by the reaction of a few people who think otherwise.

Comment: @drat No sir, it was not triggered by your great answer but it seems the guys here wants me to PROVE that every question I ask is "based on actual problems that I face" else they will call me a troll! I accepted the fact that my last question is difficult to accept but now this Anti-Muslims wants to strip me of my religion as well! I'll post a proof for the bullet proof vest when I am at work but I highly doubt my boss will agree on posting a photo for the gold bar for obvious reasons. It's just sad that you make your judgements based on speculations

Comment: This answer is getting downvoted as it doesn't constructivley deal with the issue raised in the question. The question itself is getting downvoted because it's confrontational and unconstructive. As you say this is NOT Reddit, and by and large people here are more disciplined with up/down votes.

Comment: @CMaster so how do you suggest that I prove my questions are real?

Comment: @User I suggest that you don't bother, and ignore those who demand that you do. I have some doubts about the genuine *need* to know for some of your questions, but that hasn't stopped me answering when the question itself if completely valid and of *conceivable* interest to travellers, or caused me to downvote a well-written question.

Comment: @CMaster well said, I have no problem with getting down voted or having my questions put on hold. I have problem with people who called me mentally ill, smart ass, liar and a troll!

Comment: I don't see the point of your answer. I'm therefore flagging it. Answers are not meant for flame wars. Neither are questions of course but that's the object of another flag explanation comment.