# General Ignorance: A plea for tolerance

Tags: discussion, policy

Lots of people have misconceptions about various destinations. Personally, I've been guilty of:

1. Thinking Tokyo would have been badly affected by the 2011 earthquake and tsunami.
2. Thinking Tokyo would be a difficult destination for solo English-speakers.

not to mention non-travel related misconceptions about Japanese culture, such as thinking that Japanese people wore chopsticks in their [hair](http://justhungry.com/your-guide-better-chopstick-etiquette-mostly-japanese).

If someone has a misconception about a country, such as thinking Japanese people [don't eat meat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/non-seafood-food-options-in-tokyo) or that it's unsafe to stay in a prefecture next to Fukushima prefecture for [eight hours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/are-there-any-good-radiation-measurement-devices-to-recommend-when-traveling-to), by all means correct them of their misconception, but don't ridicule them.

Comment: @pnuts I linked to two TSE questions in the last paragraph, one of which was mocked.

Comment: @pnuts this comment in particular: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/non-seafood-food-options-in-tokyo#comment102765_51286

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first rule of Travel.SE is <strike>not talk about Travel.SE</strike> [be nice](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/108). Always valid.