# Rude, pointless or lengthy chats in comments

Tags: discussion, community

We've been getting a TON of mod notifications recently for rude, abusive, pointless (chatty) or lengthy chats in comments.

We get auto notifications for lengthy ones and will clean them up, but we don't want to have to as sometimes we miss useful snippets among the mess.

Please remember comments are NOT for discussions.  Take it to the chat.

In addition, some users are repeatedly getting flags for overly sarcastic/rude/attacking comments.  Please try and keep it civil, and [be nice to users, old and new](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/rule-1-be-nice).

We do notice who tend to be in these conversations, and if someone is rude or attacking, please don't engage, do flag them, and we'll look into it and take action if needed.

Comment: Big Brother is watching.

Comment: Sarcastically mischaracterizing someone else's viewpoint is abuse, right? Or attacking their motives.

Comment: @JoErNanO actually no, that's not the point, we don't want to have to be watching every single comment thread when it gets out of control.  Moderators shouldn't need to get flagged as people shouldn't be engaging in discussions in comments.  When they do, that's when we get flagged :/

Comment: @smci generalising makes it difficult, but we're not going to work through examples here.  The point was to try and reduce the number of discussions and arguments, and to get people to flag stuff instead of engaging or arguing :)

Comment: @MarkMayo: In *1984* (which JoErNanO is alluding to), a key component of the system is citizens reporting on each other. So if the moderation regime is creepy and authoritarian, then "Big Brother is watching" is equally applicable to moderation flags as to moderators watching every single comment thread. (Though FWIW, I suspect that JoErNanO is at least half-joking. Moderation on Stack Exchange is often excessive and sometimes authoritarian, but deletion of comments is a far cry from torture and reeducation. It's just a bit frustrating sometimes.)

Comment: @pnuts flag anything offensive or rude